# Using React.js minimally with Express.js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am in the process of full-stack engineering a web application. As the front-end framework I want to use React. I've learned JSX and I'm ready to build components; however there are many other frameworks and complications going in with React.

I am using express.js for routing and passport.js for securing the routing process. However, looking at several tutorials and forums I keep seeing other routing handling methods such as React Router.

My question is as follows, may I use React.js as a variation of templating engine? In other words, I'll use EJS for dynamically serve HTML and use React's component based approach to "texturize" the served markup. Is this possible or do I have to use React Router or some React features such as React history etc.?

Comment: You are confusing yourself with back-end routing and front-end routing. What you can do is create an API using Express.js and consume that API in the front-end using React. This is also known as a Single Page Application. React Router is used for routing in your browser, it doesn't do anything in the back-end. React Router keeps your UI in sync with the URL.

Comment: @SaugatAcharya "React Router is used for routing in your browser, it doesn't do anything in the back-end" thank you for this. Makes a lot of sense. Thank you.